# useradd Problem with /etc/default/useradd ubuntu 22.04

Tags: users, user-management, useradd

**Hi i have problem with useradd conf file /etc/default/useradd. I change some vaule at the end of file**

for example:

GROUP=100

HOME=/users

INACTIVE=40

EXPIRE=4

SKEL=/etc/skel

CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes

**none of the values work. when i type useradd -D i see default value not mine.**

File: (I only edit create mail spool)

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the full /etc/default/useradd ?

Comment: @Lutz ok i edit the question